# Batch file to work with bulk copy utility

Tags: batch-file, bcp

I'm trying to create a batch file which will check my bcp, *(bulk copy program)*, utility injection result.

I would like the script to check if the path saves correctly, show me any errors and provide some form of timing mechanism.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: You need to start by providing, in your question, the complete bcp command line you're using, _including real paths and all arguments etc._. Then you need to try to show us the format of the output when run, and what you would like to do with it. You also need to try to do your own research and show us what you've learned or tried yourself, otherwise your code request is off topic here. If you [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46641887/edit) it will allow you to edit your question in order to append the required information.

Comment: i have manage to get that sorted but i have one things which i do not know how do it  :
create a batch that will verifiy the file format 
for example make sure the file is txt, or csv if not then report a error if 
if you know what i mean 
Thanks

Comment: MK55SDV, if you want people to provide help read the first two sentences and last sentence of my previous comment, and do as they requested.